# Processing JSON into new format in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I currently use this code to reformat my json into the format I want:

```
  let input = {
      "Apples": {
        "Apples_pos1": 501.82,
        "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
        "Apples_pos3": 502.61,
        "Apples": 502.16,
      }
    };

    let output = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, outerKey) => {
      for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(input[outerKey])) {
        acc.push([outerKey, value, key.split('_')[1] || key]);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);

    console.log(output);
```

```js
[
   [
      "Apples",
      501.82,
      "pos1"
   ],
   [
      "Apples",
      502.61,
      "pos2"
   ],
   [
      "Apples",
      502.61,
      "pos3"
   ],
   [
      "Apples",
      502.16,
      "Apples"
   ]
]
```

If my input instead looked like this:

```
let second_input = {
  "Apples": {
    "11-26-19": {
      "Apples_pos1": 501.82,
      "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
      "Apples_pos3": 502.61,
      "Apples": 502.16,
    }
  }
};
```

And this is my desired output:

```js
[
   [
      "Apples",
      501.82,
      "pos1",
      "11-26-19"
   ],
   [
      "Apples",
      502.61,
      "pos2",
      "11-26-19"
   ],
   [
      "Apples",
      502.61,
      "pos3",
      "11-26-19"
   ],
   [
      "Apples",
      502.16,
      "Apples",
      "11-26-19"
   ]
]
```

How could I edit my old code to be able to produce this desired output?

Thanks.

Comment: Just write the logic for this new data, just like you did for the older one. What's the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go one more layer deep, because you're now iterating over a subarray.

*Explanation of Approach:* I kept the style of code you had used, by doing another `for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(...))` call -- this way, your code continues to resemble what it was before.  If you need to go *another layer deep*, just follow the same procedure again, and knowing what to do should be no problem.  In this case, continuity of code is a good thing!  In the code, notice our new vars, `subkey` and `subvalue`...

```
let output = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, outerKey) => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(input[outerKey])) {
    for (let [subkey, subvalue] of Object.entries(input[outerKey][key])) {
        var goodsubkey = subkey.replace(/^outerKey + '_'/, '');
        acc.push([outerKey, subvalue, goodsubkey, key]);
    }
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Also, your `arr.split(_)[1]` call was a bit unclear, and it certainly won't work on increasingly, longer keys.  So, I replaced this naturally with `arr.replace(/^outerKey + '_'/, '');`, which will have that forward compatibility.  For instance, this key would break on your old code: `Apples_pos1_pos2`, etc..

Made a [**fully, working demo**](https://jsbin.com/fezipin/4/edit?html,js,console).  Output...

```
[["Apples", 501.82, "pos1", "11-26-19"], ["Apples", 502.61, "pos2", "11-26-19"], ["Apples", 502.61, "pos3", "11-26-19"], ["Apples", 502.16, "Apples", "11-26-19"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

My try for this task, just modified the script a bit:

```
  let input = {
     "Apples": {
        "11-26-19": {
          "Apples_pos1": 501.82,
          "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
          "Apples_pos3": 502.61,
          "Apples": 502.16,
        }
      }
    };

    let output = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, outerKey) => {
       Object.entries(input[outerKey]).forEach(([date, item]) => {
          for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
            acc.push([outerKey, value, key.split('_')[1] || key, date]);
          }
       });
      return acc;
    }, []);

    console.log(output);
```

Output:

```
[
  [
    "Apples",
    501.82,
    "pos1",
    "11-26-19"
  ],
  [
    "Apples",
    502.61,
    "pos2",
    "11-26-19"
  ],
  [
    "Apples",
    502.61,
    "pos3",
    "11-26-19"
  ],
  [
    "Apples",
    502.16,
    "Apples",
    "11-26-19"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```js
let input = {
  "Apples": {
    "11-26-19": {
      "Apples_pos1": 501.82,
      "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
      "Apples_pos3": 502.61,
      "Apples": 502.16,
    }
  }
};

let output = [];

Object.keys(input).map(key1 => {
  Object.keys(input[key1]).map(key2 => {
    for(let key3 in input[key1][key2]) {
      output.push([key1, input[key1][key2][key3], key3.split('_')[1] || key3.split('_')[0], key2]);
    }
  });
})

console.log(output);
```